# Pseudo or lax algebras for a 2-monad, reference request

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, operads, monads

I would like to find explicit definitions of pseudo, or even lax, algebras for a 2-monad, and their lax morphisms, *with all the coherence diagrams included*.

Alternatively, coherent lax algebras for an operad would also be welcome.

What would be a reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original reference is Marta C. Bunge, "Coherent extensions and relational algebras", Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 197 (1974), pp. 355-390.